# Dynamic text on top of wx.SplashScreen

Tags: python, wxpython, splash-screen

I am using wxPython to create a splash screen.  It actually works great, but now I want to put some loading feedback on the splashscreen.  Does anyone know how I can put a dynamic label on top of the splashscreen?  Here is the code I am using:

```
class myFrame(wxFrame):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, _("Radar"), 
                      size=(800, 600), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)


class MySplash(wx.SplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        aBitmap = wx.Image(name=VarFiles["Radar_Splash"]).ConvertToBitmap()
        splashStyle = wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN | wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT
        splashDuration = 12000 # ms
        wx.SplashScreen.__init__(self, aBitmap, splashStyle, splashDuration, parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.CloseSplash)
        wx.Yield()
    def CloseSplash(self, evt):
        self.Hide()
        global frame
        frame = myFrame(parent=None)
        app.SetTopWindow(frame)
        frame.Show(True)
        evt.Skip()

class MyAwesomeApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        MySplash = MySplash()
        MySplash.Show()
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

As the `SplashScreen` is essentially a window displaying a bitmap, you will need to modify the provided bitmap, doing the layouting yourself.

```
def _draw_bmp(bmp, txt_lst):
    dc = wx.MemoryDC()
    dc.SelectObject(bmp)
    dc.Clear()
    gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
    font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
    gc.SetFont(font)
    for i, line in enumerate(txt_lst):
        dc.DrawText(line, 10, i * 20 + 15)
    dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

    # ...
        aBitmap = #...
        _draw_bmp(aBitmap, ['splash', 'screen', 'text'])
```

The `wx.GraphicsContext` will be helpful to have antialiased text looking the same as in the underlying OS.

Comment: Would I have to call that every time I wanted to text to

Comment: Ahh, now I understand "dynamic": I meant dynamic in the sense that the bitmap text is generated during runtime, you were meaning that the text on the bitmap **changes** during runtime. Have tried a ``PaintDC`` and a timer, but did not see changing text. You could try ``wx.lib.agw.AdvancedSplash`` (I personally I am not a huge fan, because AGW items look often less generic than the core part of wx).